# Intel Core i7-4790K running rather hot with boxed cooler

Tags: cpu, cooling

I am running a Core i7-4790K with the bundled cooler that came in the boxed version of the processor.

From an old Sandy Bridge system I built I had the experience that the boxed cooler was actually quite sufficient and even under maximum load it had stayed under the 70°C mark.

Now my new Haswell chip runs quite hotter with the bundled cooler with around 40°C at idle and under almost maximum load at around 100°C!

Is this normal for the new processors with boxed coolers or did I maybe screw up the thermal paste (which was actually already applied stock on the cooler)?

Thanks for your answers!

EDIT: I read some reviews of the boxed version of this processor on Amazon and it seems like a lot of people experience the same. So my guess is that it's not me potentially installing the cooler in a wrong way but actually a design flaw in the bundled cooler.

Comment: It’s definitely not normal. Check that all pushpins are properly anchored.

Comment: 72c should be max. http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2210400/4790k-temperatures.html

Comment: @DanielB so you would say that the boxed cooler should perform better?

Comment: @DanielB I just checked all the pushpins again and they are all perfectly seated.
So would you say, that it's time for a different cooler?

Comment: Unless your PC has a severely clogged up ventilation system, the boxed cooler should keep your CPU well within specified operating parameters. It would be quite pointless otherwise. Of course an aftermarket cooler would be more efficient and silent.

Comment: @DanielB that was my experience with boxed coolers as well in the past. but this one seems to be different. some people on Amazon talk about the same issue.

Comment: It's not a design flaw, it's just the CPU giving you as much performance as it possibly can.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly the issue will be due to one of the following and all should be investigated and ruled out as a first step.

**CPU Fan**
The fan on the boxed cooling may not be working or working poorly. Inspect for function, dust and noticeable movement of air (don't chomp any fingers).

**Case Air**
Sufficient movement of air through the case to remove heat around the CPU cooler. Exhaust air is probably the first thing I'd look at, ensure plenty of air is being drawn out of the case and when the CPU temp is reading high the case exhaust air is noticeably warm.

**CPU Thermal Paste**
Some pastes can deteriorate over time. Some are just not as good at thermal conductivity as others. People are known to forget to use it or use it incorrectly. Get some good quality paste and re-mount the factory cooler.
There should be just enough used that when the CPU heatsink is fixed to the motherboard the paste spreads to the edges of the contact area.